# Any way to use make-kpg to build a Debian kernel based on a pre-built image?

Tags: linux, compilation, kernel, debian, cross-compiling

I'm working with a complex cross compiled environment.  I want to make a .deb file of my kernel.  I already have a shell script that builds the correct targets.

My existing i386 build uses make-kpkg to build a .deb file.  Is there any way to get make-kpkg to just package up existing built binaries?

Or can anyone suggest any other good means of creating a .deb file for my kernel?

Comment: Why not just rebuild the desired kernel with `make-kpkg`?

Comment: I'm having problems getting that to work, plus I already have a script that does the build, plus the build is more complex than a regular x86 build in that various cross compiler tools need to be used.